# Where is "OSGi Deployment Package Definition" support in the latter Eclipse versions?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, kura

In the Eclipse old versions, the OSGi Application Deployment Tools included the management of .dpp files. Is it possible to re-add the plugin for enable this function in current IDE 2020‑12?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong: this feature is part of the mtoolkit plugin. Installing it adds all the DPP file management stuff to Eclipse (wizard, editor, etc.).